# Sharepoint 2013 and Html5 Video

Tags: 2013, video, html5

Does anyone know why (or can they point me in the right direction) my html5 video is not playing on my sharepoint page?

Unfortunately it is defaulting to the silverlight player every time and I am stuck on a permanent buffer). I'm sure there has to be literature for this and if anyone knows where it is can they point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are using IE9+ ? IE8 and lower does not support html5 video

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Video JS files and upload into Style Library

   [video.js](http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3.0/video.js)

   [video-js.css](http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3.0/video-js.css)

   [video-js.swf](http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3.0/video-js.swf)
2. Upload Video file and a poster (image) to Site Assets
3. Edit page and add a Script Editor Web Part
4. Paste following in the Script Editor Web Part window

   ```
   <link href="/Style%20Library/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Style%20Library/video.js"></script>
   <script>
       videojs.options.flash.swf = "/Style%20Library/video-js.swf"
   </script>

   <div style="width:576;height:324;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
       <video id="SPvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" preload="auto" 
       data-setup="{'example_option':true}" controls="true" 
       poster="/SiteAssets/VideoPreviewFrame.jpg" height="324" width="576"> 
           <source type="video/mp4″ src="/SiteAssets/MyCoolVideo.mp4"> 
       </video>
   </div>
   ```

Change `VideoPreviewFrame.jpg` with your poster image

Change `MyCoolVideo.mp4` with your video file name